# Application Insights - first trace is not collected

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-application-insights

I have a console application sending some logs to App Insights:

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Logger.Log("test1");
    Logger.Log("test2");
    Logger.Log("test3");
    ...
}
```

Logger looks like this:

```cs
public static class Logger
{
    private static TelemetryClient _logger;

    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        _GetLogger().TrackTrace(message);
        _Flush();
    }

    private static TelemetryClient _GetLogger()
    {
        if (_logger is null) _logger = _GetTelemetryClient();
        return _logger;
    }

    ...
}
```

I discovered that the first message does not get to AI. Others do.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: If there is more than one thread in the picture, it can be positive concurrency in `_GetLogger()` method: `if (_logger is null)` check may be passed couple times before _logger is actually set for the first time. First Telemetry Client instances (the first to be created) will be stale/orphaned then. `_Flush()` will flush the telemetry from the last one.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion - yet the environment is single threaded, that's why I did not put any locks.

Comment: Do you leverage ServerTelemetryChannel (will be installed if Microsoft.AI.Web package is used) for telemetry delivery or InMemoryChannel (will be there if AI API package is used)? I tried reproducing and all messages were sent for me even without Sleep in the Flush().

Comment: What is the best way to know? I have both installed. As a random measure, I removed the `ServerTelemetryChannel` package (do I force the other one thereby?), this did not change the situation.

Comment: ApplicationInsights.config file contains the channel name. If config still mentions `ServerTelemetryChannel` but the package was removed, you may have an exception in AI initialization. But, it there is no configuration file, then `InMemoryChannel` is used as default. You may also try `DeveloperMode` mode set to true on `TelemetryConfiguration.Active` - this will disable batching and will Flush() after every event - not recommended from the performance standpoint, but something to try out.

Comment: Oh I see, so I was using `ServerTelemetryChannel`. Adding `DeveloperMode` does not change much. When I remove `ApplicationInsights.config`, no messages are sent at all, regardless of `DeveloperMode`.

Comment: Removing configuration file might've deleted Instrumentation Key and the data was not sent because it didn't have any destination. If you remove config, can you try setting Instrumentation Key in code via `TelemetryConfiguration.Active`?

Comment: Well, actually I have it this way, from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below, and it works for me:

In Program.cs:

```
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Logger.Log("test 1");
            Logger.Log("test 2");
            Logger.Log("test 3");

            await Logger.DoSomethingAsync();

        }
```

In Logger.cs:

```
    public static class Logger
    {
        private static TelemetryClient _logger;

        public static void Log(string message)
        {
            _GetLogger().TrackTrace(message);
            _Flush();
        }

        public static TelemetryClient _GetLogger()
        {
            if (_logger is null)
            {
                TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "your key";
                _logger = new TelemetryClient();

            }

            return _logger;

        }

        public static void _Flush()
        {
            if (_logger is null)
            {
                TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "your key";
                _logger = new TelemetryClient();

            }

            _logger.Flush();
        }

        public static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }

    }
```

After execution, all the messages are shown in azure portal:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion - tried that. This actually in my case leads to no logs at all, because in my `Flush` method I merely `Thread.Sleep` for 3 sec, otherwise it won't send a thing.